# python - how to split an input string into an array?

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to create a very simple program for averaging numbers. And one part of it involves converting an input string into an array.

E.g.

```
average = input()
```

average becomes 'Hello world! This is a string.'

I then need to split it into an array like this:

```
average = ['Hello', 'world!', 'This', 'is', 'a', 'string.']
```

What would be a way of going about this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `split` function :

```
lst = txt.split(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
separator = " "
average = input()
print average.split(separator)
```

There is a inbuilt method called `split()` which will get your job done , you can pass a separator variable to that method indicating the character you want to split upon However the default value is `space` " " itself , `averge.split()` would also work fine in your case.