# Creating a dynamic array in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a dynamic array in which I would like to update the userstring, e.g.,
for a 25 character single string like 'mannysattynastysillyfully'. there would be a 5x5 array .

```
m a n n y
s a t t y
n a s t y
s i l l y
f u l l y
```

I have tried multiple things and went through extensive search with bit of information that I got from 
1. [How to define two-dimensional array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python)
2. [How to take input in an array + PYTHON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845165/how-to-take-input-in-an-array-python)
3.[python - how to split an input string into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577229/python-how-to-split-an-input-string-into-an-array)

Am still unable to comprehend how i should be dealing with the user values getting into the dynamic array

Comment: what exactly do you mean by `dynamic array`

Comment: @Thomas mean the array sizes it self according to the user string, for eg., if the string is 25chr long the array would size as 5x5

Comment: There really isn't a native multidimensional array in python. There are a few libraries that can do this including pandas and tablib. You could also just use a list of lists, or something like that.

Comment: The real problem is that I am not sure how you are deciding a 25 character string should be a 5x5 array.  If it were a 24 character string, would it be 3x8,  8x3, 6x4, etc? Maybe we add an extra space somewhere and force it to 5x5. You would either need a delimiter in your data, or provide the width or count of names.  I really can't think of a scenario where someone would enter in names like that though, how are you ending up with 'mannysattynastysillyfully'?

Comment: @JamesRobinson the n in the nxn matrix is odd so whatever the string is it goes straight into that matrix, if there is an extra space at the end it is kept as blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may do what you are after:

```
>>> def two_dim(inval, width=5):
...     out = []
...     for i in range(0, len(inval) - 1, width):
...         out.append(list(inval[i:i + width]))
...     return out
...
>>> print(two_dim('mannysattynastysillyfully'))
[['m', 'a', 'n', 'n', 'y'], ['s', 'a', 't', 't', 'y'], ['n', 'a', 's', 't', 'y'], ['s', 'i', 'l', 'l', 'y'], ['f', 'u', 'l', 'l', 'y']]
```

And to print it like you have in the question:

```
>>> c = two_dim('mannysattynastysillyfully')
>>> for sub in c:
...     print " ".join(sub)
...
m a n n y
s a t t y
n a s t y
s i l l y
f u l l y
```

**NOTE**  This will only create complete rows, so using a width that is not a factor of the length of the input string will result in lost data.  This is easy to change if desired, but I will leave that as an exercise to the reader.

If you are looking to always create a square 2x2, then you could do something like

```
def is_square(l):
    return math.floor(math.sqrt(l))**2 == l

def two_dim_square(inval):
    if not is_square(len(inval)):
        raise Exception("string length is not a perfect square")
    width = math.sqrt(len(inval))
    # proceed like before with a derived width
```

**EDIT 2**

```
def two_dim(inval, width=5):
    out = []
    for i in range(0, len(inval) - 1, width):
        out.append(list(inval[i:i + width]))
    return out

def print_array(label, inval, joiner=' '):
    print label
    for sub in inval:
        print joiner.join(sub)
    print

print_array("3 by X", two_dim('mannysattynastysillyfully', 3))
print_array("4 by X", two_dim('mannysattynastysillyfully', 4))
print_array("5 by X", two_dim('mannysattynastysillyfully', 5))
print_array("6 by X", two_dim('mannysattynastysillyfully', 6))
```

Gives the output

```
3 by X
m a n
n y s
a t t
y n a
s t y
s i l
l y f
u l l

4 by X
m a n n
y s a t
t y n a
s t y s
i l l y
f u l l

5 by X
m a n n y
s a t t y
n a s t y
s i l l y
f u l l y

6 by X
m a n n y s
a t t y n a
s t y s i l
l y f u l l
```

**EDIT 3**
If you want all data to always be present, and use a default value for empty cells, then that would look like

```
def two_dim(inval, width=5, fill=' '):
    out = []
    # This just right-pads the input string with the correct number of fill values so the N*M is complete.
    inval = inval + (fill * (width - (len(inval) % width)))
    for i in range(0, len(inval) - 1, width):
        out.append(list(inval[i:i + width]))
    return out
```

Called with

```
print_array("3 by X", two_dim('mannysattynastysillyfully', 3, '*'))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
3 by X
m a n
n y s
a t t
y n a
s t y
s i l
l y f
u l l
y * *
```

Comment: excellent answer, thanks just a nudge as of what can be done if the width has to be decided on the fly

Comment: What do you mean - "if the width has to be decided on the fly"?

Comment: i mean if the width of the array is to be decided by the user

Comment: @Smple_V Is there still a question, or do you already understand now?

Comment: just have to figure out a way  to fix the width of the array. Mean like instead of giving it a static number

Comment: The example I showed, `def two_dim(inval, width=5)` has a **default** width of 5, but you can pass in any value you like.  `c = two_dim('yourstring', 4)` for example.  My note about taking only complete rows still applies though and you would get `[['y', 'o', 'u', 'r'], ['s', 't', 'r', 'i']]` in that case.

Comment: See my **EDIT 2** above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109278/discussion-between-smple-v-and-sberry).