# Making a list out of input in python

Tags: python, list

If our input was two numbers in a line. And these numbers were greater than 10. How can I make a list out of them by separating them properly?
For example:

Input:10 20

```
X=List(input()):['1','0',' ','2','0']
```

But i want to be like this:

```
X=['10',' ','20']
```

Comment: Regex split will work: `import re; re.split('(\W)', input())`  [In Python, how do I split a string and keep the separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2136580)

Comment: 10 is not greater than 10.  The question is unclear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python - how to split an input string into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577229/python-how-to-split-an-input-string-into-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split):

```
x = input().split()
print(x)
# ['10', '20']
```

I assume that you do not want the whitespace separator in between (that is, not `['10', ' ', '20']`).

If you need to convert the strings to numeric type, use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
x = [int(y) for y in input().split()]
print(x)
# [10, 20]
```

Then you can do numeric operations such as this, which results in a list with a single element, 20:

```
x = [y for y in x if y > 10]
print(x)
# [20]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
from sys import argv
print ([int(_) for _ in list(argv[1].split(',')) if int(_) > 10])
```